# data.table apply function on each column

Tags: r, loops, set, data.table, lapply

I guess I am pretty close to a solution, but I struggle to combine lapply with data.table. I read a lot about lapply and find some example with data.table, but the way of thinking is new to me and its driving me nuts...

This is my data.table

```
cells <- c(150, 1,1980,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2004,3,
       99 , 1,1980,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2004,4,
       899, 1,1980,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,2007,4,
       789, 1,1982,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,2004,3 )
colname <- c("number","sex", "birthy", "2004","2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009","2010","begy","SeqLen")
rowname <- c("2","3","4","5")
y <- matrix(cells, nrow=4, ncol=12, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(rowname,colname))
y <- data.table(y, keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

I want to step through a vector of column names

```
cols <- c(paste(2004:2010, sep=" "))
```

Doing the following operation on just one column works fine!

```
vec <- "2005"
y[,  (vec) := ifelse((vec) < as.numeric(begy),0, ifelse( ((vec) > as.numeric(begy) + as.numeric(SeqLen) -1) ,0,1)) ]
```

Creating a function and stepping through the vector seams a good solution, but how? 
I found this...

```
dt[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, "*", -1), .SDcols = cols]
```

but where can I put my ifelse in this example?

I also read about for-loop and set function, like this...

```
for (j in cols) set(dt, j = j, value = ifelse((dt[[j]]) < as.numeric(dt[[begy]]),0, ifelse( (dt[[j]] > as.numeric(dt[[begy]]) + as.numeric(dt[[SeqLen]]) -1) ,0,1)))
```

but this is nonsense.

Thanks
Alina

Comment: Create a function such as `f <- function(x) ifelse(x < as.numeric(begy) etc...` and then use it as in the example you found `dt[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = cols]`. Regarding your function itself, I would recommend you to Google up how to avoid embedded `ifelse` statements.

Comment: I created a function like you suggested and used this function. But I receive a error message "Object begy not found". I suppose, only the columns in cols are available for the transformation?

Comment: So add it as a parameter, e.g. `f <- function(x, begy) x * begy ; y[, lapply(.SD, f, begy), .SDcols = cols]`. Creating functions and using `lapply` is really basic R operations and not related to data.table

Comment: Got me, I am a beginner and learning new stuff every day. But still your example does not work ...I tried this...`f <- function(x,begy, SeqLen){

  ifelse(x < as.numeric(begy),0, ifelse( (x > as.numeric(begy) + as.numeric(SeqLen) -1) ,0,1))
}

y[, lapply(.SD, f, begy,SeqLen), .SDcols = cols]` but the output is not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are setting the years columns with 1 if it is between `begy` and `begy + SeqLen - 1` for each row. Here is another way to do this:

```
y[order(rn), 
    (grep("^20", names(y), value=TRUE)) := 
        dcast(y[, seq(begy, by=1, length.out=SeqLen), by=.(rn)], rn ~ V1, length)[,-1L]]
y
```

output:

```
   rn number sex birthy 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 begy SeqLen
1:  2    150   1   1980    1    1    1    0    0    0    0 2004      3
2:  3     99   1   1980    1    1    1    1    0    0    0 2004      4
3:  4    899   1   1980    0    0    0    1    1    1    1 2007      4
4:  5    789   1   1982    1    1    1    0    0    0    0 2004      3
```

Explanation:

Create a sequence of years for each row, then use `dcast` to do a one-hot encoding. Use the output to overwrite the years columns.

`order(rn)` will ensure that we don't overwrite rows incorrectly after `dcast`

---

Frank's method is way faster:

```
y[, as.character(2004:2010) := 
    lapply(2004:2010, function(x) as.integer(between(x, begy, begy + SeqLen - 1)))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will need some time to understand your solution. Do you think it is a bad idea to name the variables with the years? Because 2004 could also be read as number? For example y[,.(number,SeqLen,"2004")] is creating a new variable 2004 instead of selecting the variable 2004.

Comment: you can use backtick `2004` in this case. Or rename your columns to YEAR_xxxx

Comment: I have one more question regarding your solution. The output is correct, but I get a hole bunch of warnings regarding datatype being integer instead of double and value.var. Do you also get these warnings?

Comment: Never mind, this works... y[, names(y) := lapply(.SD, as.integer)]

Comment: Fwiw, `y[, lapply(2004:2010, function(x) as.integer(between(x, begy, begy + SeqLen - 1)))]` seems to work, since op is not iterating over columns but rather column names (which are just 2004:2010)